# Short form of dedication in Greek? "Αφιερωμένο σε~" -> "Στον ~" or something else?

Tags: greek-language

**Note:** I am asking this question here because a number of other questions have suggested that there is no Greek StackExchange and that these questions should be asked in Literature StackExchange. If I am in the wrong, I'd be happy to post this question elsewhere.

In English, I can say "Dedicated to Michael" or, more briefly, "To Michael."

In Greek, is shortening "Αφιερωμένο στον Μιχάλη" to "Στον Μιχάλη" valid?

Comment: Just to be clear: this is about dedications to people at the front of Greek literary works, right? I think that makes it on topic, but general translation questions about ancient Greek are off-topic everywhere on StackExchange.

Comment: @cmw The former case is precisely what I am interested in.